# Conditonally transform column values to values of different type

Tags: r

With a data frame like below:

```
set.seed(100)
dfm <- data.frame(id = sample(1:5, 6, replace = TRUE),
                  val1 = rep(c("true", "false"), 3), 
                  val2 = sample(c("true", "false"), 6, replace = TRUE))

  id  val1  val2
1 31  true false
2 26 false  true
3 56  true false
4  6 false  true
5 47  true false
6 49 false false
```

with base R , need to change the values in col `val1` to `TRUE` (R logical true) if value is `"true"` and `FALSE` if value is `"false"`. Similarly change values in col `val2` to `1` if value is `"true"` and 0 if value is `"false"`.

Comment: try `dfm$val1 == "true"` and `as.integer(dfm$val2 == "true")`

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use:

```
dfm$val1 = dfm$val1 == "true"
dfm$val2 = as.integer(dfm$val2 == "true")
```