# R - mutate multiple column values conditionally

Tags: r

With a data frame like below:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(id = sample(1:5, 6, replace = TRUE),
                 val1 = rep(c("true", "false"), 3), 
                 val2 = sample(c("true", "false"), 6, replace = TRUE))

  id  val1  val2
1 31  true false
2 26 false  true
3 56  true false
4  6 false  true
5 47  true false
6 49 false false
```

Need to change the values in col `val1` and `val2` to `TRUE` (R logical true) if value is `"true"` and `FALSE` if value is `"false"`.

This can be done via

```
df$val1 <- df$val1 == "true"
df$val2 <- df$val2 == "true"
```

While the above works, I have a case where the number of columns run in to 100s. So need a way to where the columns to mutate can be specified - like `df[,2:3]` in the example above. While base R solution is preferred, others are welcome.

Comment: I would simply go with `df[-1] <- as.logical(unlist(df[-1]))`. Look in `?TRUE`: "*as.logical attempts to coerce its argument to be of logical type. For factors, this uses the levels (labels). Like as.vector it strips attributes including names. Character strings c("T", "TRUE", "True", "true") are regarded as true, c("F", "FALSE", "False", "false") as false, and all others as NA.*". So basically R is familiar with `"true"` and `"false"`

Comment: Why do you open a second question for this after asking almost exactly the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084356/conditonally-transform-column-values-to-values-of-different-type

Comment: It is not "almost exactly the same question" - why do you think so ?

Comment: Your previous question is a specific case of this question. So I closed it with this one.

Answer (score 5):

@DavidArenburg's answer in comment with explanations of how R handles `logical`s needs to be a real answer imo, copying and pasting it here:

You can simply go with

```
df[-1] <- as.logical(unlist(df[-1]))
```

Look in `?TRUE`:

> *as.logical attempts to coerce its argument to be of logical type. For factors, this uses the levels (labels). Like as.vector it strips
>   attributes including names. Character strings c("T", "TRUE", "True",
>   "true") are regarded as true, c("F", "FALSE", "False", "false") as
>   false, and all others as NA.*

So basically R is familiar with `"true"` and `"false"` and knows how to handle them

Answer (score 4):

We can use base R

```
df[, 2:3] <- df[, 2:3] == "true"

df
#  id  val1  val2
#1  2  TRUE FALSE
#2  2 FALSE  TRUE
#3  3  TRUE FALSE
#4  1 FALSE  TRUE
#5  3  TRUE FALSE
#6  3 FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mutate_at` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
df %<>%
     mutate_at(vars(val1:val2), funs(.=="true"))
df
#  id  val1  val2
#1  2  TRUE FALSE
#2  2 FALSE  TRUE
#3  3  TRUE FALSE
#4  1 FALSE  TRUE
#5  3  TRUE FALSE
#6  3 FALSE FALSE
```

---

Another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, `==`, "true"), .SDcols = 2:3]
```

---

Or an efficient `base R` approach is

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], `==`, "true")
df
#  id  val1  val2
#1  2  TRUE FALSE
#2  2 FALSE  TRUE
#3  3  TRUE FALSE
#4  1 FALSE  TRUE
#5  3  TRUE FALSE
#6  3 FALSE FALSE
```